# Where can I get a full line height true type font

Tags: fonts, truetype

I need a font for an Android application that fills the line so I can control the space above and below the characters.  In other words, no space for descenders below the letters or accents above them.  Kind of like this sketch.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to make one by scaling an existing font using Type 3.2